# undefined symbol: _ZTIN10tensorflow8OpKernelE

Tags: tensorflow, undefined, symbols

I just updated tensorflow with pip3 (now to version 1.4.1). After it I am having problems:

I have a custom op library that I compile with -D _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0. The library compiles and links fine. Importing it into tensorflow gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "../x.py", line 29, in <module>
    lib = tf.load_op_library(_lib_path)
  File "/home/ilge/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 56, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename, status)
  File "/home/ilge/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /path/to/mylib.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN10tensorflow8OpKernelE
```

It seems it cannot load general tensorflow symbols. Hints on how I could debug it are very appreciated. Note that before the update and before recompiling everything was working.

Answer (score 2):

See the updated custom op instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#compile_the_op_using_your_system_compiler_tensorflow_binary_installation

In particular:

```
>>> tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()
['-L/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow', '-ltensorflow_framework']
```

Custom ops are now (in TensorFlow 1.4+) registered by linking against `libtensorflow_framework.so`. Previously TensorFlow loaded the necessary symbols into the global symbol table for the Python process (using `RTLD_GLOBAL`).

Answer (score 2):

I was compiling and linking in two different steps in my make file, and just using the proper link flags when linking wasn't enough. I also had to pass the argument `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to the linker, because for some reason gcc was discarding the library in the final module (as shown by ldd).

So my Makefile looks like this

```
TF_CFLAGS:=$(shell python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags()))')
TF_LFLAGS:=$(shell python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()))')

all: myop_ops.so

%.o: %.cc
    g++ -fPIC $(TF_CFLAGS) -O2 -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include -c $< -o $@

myop_ops.so: myfile1.o myfile2.o myop_kernel.o myop_ops.o
    g++ -shared -Wl,--no-as-needed $(TF_LFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be a compatibility issue between the tensorflow and gcc versions. Check the version of gcc that tensorflow uses for building and use that version of gcc to compile your custom op library.
For e.g.
I installed tensorflow 1.6.0 with Anaconda2 and it uses gcc version 7.2. So I kept getting the same error as you when I compiled custom ops with gcc 4.8/4.9/5.3. Finally, I tried with gcc 7.3 and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

```
 pip uninstall -y horovod


 pip install --no-cache-dir horovod
```

Comment: Please add little description what you are trying to do with this code block.