# undefined symbol: _ZTIN10tensorflow8OpKernelE in building a library

Tags: tensorflow, gcc, g++

Trying to build [roi-pooling](https://github.com/deepsense-ai/roi-pooling) and so file is able to be produced.
The issue is when run the sample program.

```
File "roi_pooling_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from roi_pooling_ops import roi_pooling
  File "/home/Data/Softwares/pixel_link/roi-pooling/roi_pooling/roi_pooling_ops.py", line 8, in <module>
    roi_pooling_module = tf.load_op_library(lib_path)
  File "/home/Data/Softwares/venv_p2_7_buildfromsource/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 61, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/Data/Softwares/pixel_link/roi-pooling/roi_pooling/roi_pooling.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN10tensorflow8OpKernelE
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'test' failed
```

There is one [discusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189818/undefined-symbol-ztin10tensorflow8opkernele). But no correct answer was approved by OP.

Made sure tensorflow was built from source with gcc/g++-4.8 and roi-pooling was also built with same gcc/g++ version.

My tensorflow is 1.14, gcc/g++-4.8.

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Added the following flag to makefile and all are ok now.
-L/home//lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow -ltensorflow_framework